# Executar aplicação .jar feita no swing

Tags: java, swing

Criei uma calculadora simples, com apenas a função de somar. Ao executar pela IDE ela funciona normalmente. Então construí e tentei executar a aplicação fora da IDE, porém não obtive êxito algum. Saberiam me dizer como executar ela?

Já fui ao diretório no terminal e tentei java -jar calculadora.jar, porém nada acontece, nem mesmo um retorno de erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
package my.numberaddition;

public class NumberAdditionUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public NumberAdditionUI() {
initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void initComponents() {

jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Adição de Número", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 12), new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255))); // NOI18N

jLabel1.setText("Valor 1");

jLabel2.setText("Valor 2");

jLabel3.setText("Resultado");

jButton1.setText("Limpar");
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
}
});

jButton2.setText("Calcular");
jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
}
});

javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
.addContainerGap()
.addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addComponent(jLabel3)
.addComponent(jLabel1)
.addComponent(jLabel2))
.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
.addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
.addComponent(jTextField3)
.addComponent(jTextField2)
.addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
    .addComponent(jButton2)
    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 29, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    .addComponent(jButton1)
    .addGap(27, 27, 27))
.addComponent(jTextField1))
.addGap(29, 29, 29))
);
jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
.addContainerGap()
.addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
.addComponent(jLabel1)
.addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
.addGap(18, 18, 18)
.addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
.addComponent(jLabel2)
.addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
.addGap(18, 18, 18)
.addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
.addComponent(jLabel3)
.addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
.addGap(18, 18, 18)
.addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
.addComponent(jButton2)
.addComponent(jButton1))
.addContainerGap(32, Short.MAX_VALUE))
);

jButton3.setText("Sair");
jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
}
});

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
.addContainerGap()
.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
.addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    .addComponent(jButton3)))
.addContainerGap())
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
.addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
.addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
.addComponent(jButton3)
.addGap(6, 6, 6))
);

pack();
}                     

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
System.exit(0);
}                                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
jTextField1.setText("");
jTextField2.setText("");
jTextField3.setText("");
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

float num1, num2, resultado;

num1 = Float.parseFloat (jTextField1.getText());
num2 = Float.parseFloat (jTextField2.getText());

resultado = num1+num2;

jTextField3.setText (String.valueOf (resultado));
}                                        
public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
break;
}
}
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumberAdditionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumberAdditionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumberAdditionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumberAdditionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
//</editor-fold>

/* Create and display the form */
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
new NumberAdditionUI().setVisible(true);
}
});
}
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
}
```

**O problema era que eu não havia especificado a classe principal do projeto. Utilizando o Netbeans, cliquei com o botão direito sobre o projeto/propriedades/executar e lá especifiquei minha classe principal, fazendo com o o jar passasse a ser executado normalmente.**

Comment: Alias, ja q nao ocorre nenhum erro, cade o codigo dessa aplicacao?

Comment: Esta aqui https://github.com/nelsoncbf/calculadora/blob/master/src/my/numberaddition/NumberAdditionUI.java

Comment: Nelson nao é assim que o stackoverflow funciona, voce deve editar a pergunta, adicionando um codigo aqui no site e que seja um **[mcve]** para que possamos gerar o jar tambem.

Comment: O código tem mais de 9 mil caracteres, quebrar ele para por aqui, sem bibliotecas ou demais classes ficaria difícil de executar.

Comment: Voce acessou o link? Voce deve fornecer um codigo executavel, ou seja, sem dependencias. Como espera que lhe ajudemos se nem testar e gerar um jar podemos? Acessa e leia o link para aprender.

Comment: Acessei sim, consegui postar, editando a postagem. O limite de 600 caracteres é só em comentário.

Comment: Nelson, aqui executou sem problemas, siga minhas orientacoes na resposta da pergunta linkada como duplicata, na caixa amarela, se fizer conforme la, vai funcionar.

Comment: Estou utilizando o Netbeans, infelizmente mesmo gerando o .jar, ele não é executado. Criei uma aplicação com JavaFX + Swing exibindo Hello World em janela e funcionou normalmente ao abrir o .jar. Com a calculadora o icone nem mesmo é gerado, fica aparentando como se fosse um arquivo compactado no icone, com extensão .jar.

Comment: Adicionei outra explicando no netbeans.

Comment: Sim, eu vi, obrigado. O problema nunca foi criar o .jar, o problema é que ele não esta sendo executado após criar o .jar. Quando criei o projeto ele criou o .jar sem problemas, mas só executa dentro do Netbeans, não executa em ambiente de produção, fora da IDE. Vou revisar tudo e recomeçar do zero para ver se identifico o problema, mesmo assim, muito obrigado pela ajuda Articuno.